# How to aggregate annotate fields of related models in django

Tags: python, django

My problem is a little more complicated, but I'm posting the question in the simplest possible way.

1. Annotated `total_score` in `Photo`.
2. **I would like to annotate `max_total_score` in `Person`.**

I wrote `get_queryset` of `PersonManager`, but the following error occurred.

Is there a new way?

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        photos_prefetch = models.Prefetch(
            'photos',
            Photo.objects.annotate(total_score=models.Sum('features__score'))
        )
        return super().get_queryset() \
                      .prefetch_related(photos_prefetch) \
                      .annotate(max_total_score=models.Max('photos__total_score'))


class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()


class Photo(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')


class Feature(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, models.CASCADE, related_name='features')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

shell

```
>> Person.objects.all()
# Unsupported lookup 'total_score' for BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted
```

---

I solved it by using the `values` ​​method of the `queryset`.

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        photos = Photo.objects.annotate(total_score=models.Sum('features__score'))
        photos_prefetch = models.Prefetch(
            'photos',
            photos
        )
        return super().get_queryset() \
                      .prefetch_related(photos_prefetch) \
                      .annotate(max_total_score=models.Max(photos.values('total_score')))
```